# Android- Adjust image for different screen sizes

Tags: android, image, size, screen, imageview

I currently have an `imageview` with an image. It looks perfect on my 2.7" test screen, however, when I test it on my 4.3" screen, the image is not where it should be. I am setting the height to have `dp` and I have my image file in hdpi, mdpi, and Ldpi folders. Am I doing something wrong? Or rather, is there some way to lock the place of the image so that it displays the same way in all phone sizes? 
Thanks.

The `imageview` that is not adjusting to various screen sizes is the first `imageview` (id = sdrbg)
here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:id="@+id/sdrbg"
        android:background="@drawable/sdrmaingraphic" android:layout_height="289dp"></ImageView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/canvasBOM"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/canvas" android:layout_height="100dp">
    </ImageView>
    <Button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/playpausebuttonBOM" android:background="@drawable/main_pause_button"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/nextbuttonBOM"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:background="@drawable/next_song_button"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></Button>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Best of May 2011"
        android:textSize="20dp" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="false"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There are many factors that influence the layout and size of an ImageView. Are you able to share the layout file?

Comment: @Dan: just added my layout code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying the height use `wrap_content` and RelativeLayout features to specify height. For example: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignBottom="@id/playPauseButtomBOM"` and `android:layout_marginBottom="xxdp"`

Answer (score 0):

i *think* the problem is in `android:layout_height="289dp"`, try not to control the `height`, and use `padding` instead

Comment: I will test this out and let you know the results